# Getting started with jQuery -- hiding an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have you noticed that every 10 questions on this site is about jQuery?

Anyway...

I'm using jQuery for the first time. I don't know if I loaded it correctly. When I run this code:

```
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                     function allDayClicked() {

                         if (jQuery) alert("loaded");

                         var allday = document.getElementById("allDayEvent");
                         var start = document.getElementById("<%=startTimeSelector.ClientID%>");
                         $('allDayEvent').hide();
                     }
                </script>
```

The alert appears, saying "loaded", but nothing else happens; the html checkbox doesn't go invisible. I get no kind of error in my javascript output.

Is it possible I haven't successfully loaded jQuery? I added a reference to it in my visual studio project and generated this by dragging it to default.aspx:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Otherwise, what's going on?

Comment: [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) is very good and the examples is very clear, you should take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery takes a css selector, not an id.  If you want an id use the css form of declaring an id.

```
$('#allDayEvent').hide();
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery is loaded fine, you're just using it incorrectly. You should be doing either:

```
$('#allDayEvent') // recommended, the '#' means ID
```

Or:

```
$(allday) // since you already grabbed it with getElementById
```

---

jQuery can take a lot of different objects with `$()`. The options are listed [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

Comment: that's awesome... jQuery is amazing.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the **#** in your ID selector.

Change $('allDayEvent').hide();

to

```
$('#allDayEvent').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your checkbox has an id "allDayEvent", you just need the hash (#) in this line:

```
$('#allDayEvent').hide();
```